# Spoiler text is still shown in RSS feeds, question excerpts and question tooltips

Tags: bug, status-completed, spoilers

To test, we've got feeds and everywhich way!

> So this should *not* show up in various places. Let's find out which ones!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed in chat; no more spoilers from either direct url posts, or from rss feeds that are posting SE posts into the room.

Comment: Yay! That seems to hit everywhere. Don't think there's any other way internally that we'd run into spoilers, so that should hit all.

Comment: Yaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay! :D

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** It has been fixed for the `Questions` page and for the Front page, but feeds still show it. Furthermore, forgot to check last time, but *search results also show the spoilers*.

[image: Round 2]

---

---

Still shows up in mouseover from the question list. (Among other things)

[image: Round 1]

Comment: Yeah, I've got this great image prepped up to show all the ways this is totally not working yet.

Comment: @GraceNote Oh, so this was a rhetorical question?

Comment: It's not so much rhetorical as I was just actively looking and documenting [its failure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2UDUp.png).

Comment: -1, no freehand circles in original picture (O's don't count)

Comment: @NickT I cannot be held responsible for Grace Note's escapades. (Incidentally, he's added circles, per your request)

Comment: Search results should be fixed in the next build, and tooltips should already be covered...if not which page are you still seeing tooltips on?

Comment: @GraceNote (pass along ping from Nick Craver)

Comment: @NickCraver Tooltips were fixed, it's the result in RSS feeds like in chatrooms that is a "NOOOO!" point.

Comment: @GraceNote - RSS feeds will also have it removed in a build happening in just a moment - since chat pulls from those, it should resolve the chatroom issue as well.

Comment: @GraceNote - correction on that, Marc pointed out they one box via an API fetch for more info...but he'll fix that on the chat side since we wouldn't want to change the API behavior on this...still a fix coming soon for chat.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, @NickCraver!